# Printing to a Brother Label Printer from the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, printing

I am wanting to print labels from a Brother Label Printer from a web browser. I know DYMO has a JavaScript framework that makes printing from the browser simple. But I have customers with a Brother label printer so I need to make it work.

I've been doing some testing and some searching and it's surprising how little information is out there on this subject.

So far the only browser I have had success with is Google Chrome as it doesn't seem to print header and footers. I have installed the printer/drivers and created a custom paper size which measures 62 x 29mm.

[image: Custom Paper Size]

When I try to print, it's splitting the text over 5 labels. I have the following text on the page I am trying to print:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Print</title>
</head>
<body>

<p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 13px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; border: 1px solid #000;">Line 1<br />
Line 2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But it prints 5 pages as you can see from the print que sample.

[image: Custom Paper Size]

Has anyone tackled this before or have any suggestions.

---

**UPDATE**

After changing the the margins listed in the first screenshot above to 0, it got it down to two pages. But there's still a huge margin around it:

[image: 2 Pages]

Answer (score 4):

This answer won't solve your problem in 100%. I've tested it against Safari with custom paper settings - same as ones from your example. I was testing it against printing to PDF so maybe with specific printer driver it will behave a bit different. Your example CSS and HTML are missing margin and padding reset. Here is example for @media print:

```
@media print {
    body, html, p {
        margin: 0pt !important;
        padding: 0pt !important;
    }
    @page {
       margin: 0pt !important;
       padding: 0pt !important;
    }
}
```

With this settings 2 lines of text are on one page, hover there is still some margin that can't be reduced to 0.

Comment: Had been trying to get my Dymo LaberWriter 450 Turbo to work for quite a few a hours, but just couldn't until I found this. Thank you!